# AllArgsConstructor from lombok is not found by Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lombok

When I create a new Java class with one or more field and attach the `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation from lombok to it, then i get this message

`Error:(9, 1) error: cannot find symbol class ConstructorProperties`

from the on the Gradle Build console. I was able to reproduce this by creating a new empty Android project with this configuration.

The Class (never used or instantiated)

```
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
public class Model {
    int foo;
    String bar;
}
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8'
}
```

`@Getter` and `@Setter` from lombok do not cause any problems and even the `@NoArgsConstructor` is not mentioned by gradle, so is the `AllArgsConstructor` if there are no fields.

Is this a bug from Lombok or is this bug located in front of the screen?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Lombok generates the `@ConstructorProperties` by default for all generated constructors. On Android, that annotation is not available. As mentioned in the [documentation](http://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html) it is possible to suppress the generation by either specifying `suppressConstructorProperties=true` for each @XxxArgsConstructor, or by using the following line in a high level `lombok.config` file:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true
```

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer

Comment: Hey Roel. I am having the exact same problem (I am new with lombok). I am using Android Studio 1.3 preview 4, lombok1.12.6 and lombok plugin 0.9.4.14. In my project root I have a lombok.conifg file with two lines: `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true` and `config.stopBubbling = true`. But I still get the same error as Ohem. Can you please help me?

Comment: AFAIK, Android Studio is based on IntelliJ. It could be that the IntelliJ plug-in, that is developed by a different developer, does not yet support the config system.

Comment: Aah I see. So I guess the only way is to add explicitly `@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)` right? Btw, really nice work with lombok. Keep going this way ;)

Comment: FYI, I can now use `lombok.config` with IntelliJ 14, Lombok plugin 0.9.6.14 and Lombok 1.16.4. Nice job, guys! +1

Comment: This does not work on Android studio ? I've installed plugin as well

Comment: What is the propose of `@ConstructorProperties`? What does it do? I can't find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 29):

You need to add suppression in your AllArgsConstructors. If you don't want to add a new config file, you can simply do this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)
```

Disclosure: I'm not a Lombok developer :D

Comment: Love your disclosure :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating Android Studio.

None of the another answers including accepted one helped me.

Finally I have updated the lombok version to `1.16.20` (the latest for today) and the error disappeared.

Hope it will save time for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

If you target Java 8 in your Android project (e.g. by using retrolambda) this error will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

`@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)` solution is not working anymore. If you try this, you get the following:

> This deprecated feature is no longer supported. Remove it; you can
>   create a lombok.config file with
>   'lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true'.

The working solution is adding `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true` to `lombok.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation suppressConstructorProperties is now not supported by Lombok. If you try to remove (suppressConstructorProperties = true), you would be getting the following error:

```
Error:(9, 1) error: cannot find symbol class ConstructorProperties
```

Below are the steps to solve this problem:
 1. Remove (suppressConstructorProperties = true) from the object.
 2. Go to project level dir. in your app and create a lombok.config file. 
 3. Paste below code in the config file.

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addGeneratedAnnotation = false
lombok.accessors.chain = false
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true
```