# Lombok Annotations not Working in Android

Tags: java, android, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I recently added Lombok to my Android project, and I'm getting the following error when using the @RequiredArgsConstructor and @AllArgsConstructor annotations:

```
error: cannot find symbol
@AllArgsConstructor
^
  symbol:   class ConstructorProperties
  location: package java.beans
1 error
```

I attempted to follow the solution to this question: [AllArgsConstructor from lombok is not found by Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969416/allargsconstructor-from-lombok-is-not-found-by-android-studio), however, I'm getting the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method suppressConstructorProperties()
  location: @interface AllArgsConstructor
2 errors
```

I also tried adding a `lombok.config` file with the line:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true
```

But it did't do anything. Is there any work around to this to get Lombok annotations working on Android?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to an older version of Lombok. I switched back to 1.16.10 (which is still fairly recent), and then remove the suppressConstructorProperties value in your annotation.